# How to search for a line in a file using user input through a GUI

Tags: java, search

im doing a school project, its creating a Library System.
And im having trouble coding where i have to search for a book/user.
So i have a GUI which i can enter user input what i would like to search for in my file "users.txt", and i search for stuff thats stored on the file. so Name of the user, ID, etc.
i chose search by name.

this is what my code looks like currently.

```
public void SearchUser(String UserSearchLine){

    try {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(".\\data\\users.txt"));


            while(file.hasNextLine())
            {
                UserSearchLine = file.nextLine();
                if(UserSearchLine.equals(SearchUser.usersearch));
                {
                System.out.println("found" + UserSearchLine);

                break;
                }
            }
}

            catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

this is my main class, then i have a new seperate class which creates the seperate search user GUI, and has an 'actionperformed'

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent seu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(seu.getSource() == searchBtn){
        mw.SearchUser(usersearch);
        usersearch = name.getText();

        mw.displayUsers();
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(seu.getSource() == cancelBtn){
        this.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

and i have made them variables on each class:

main class:

```
String UserSearchLine = SearchUser.usersearch;
```

searchuser class:

```
public static String usersearch;
```

so after i enter an input, like "name" and click on search button, it just prints the very first line of the text file. no matter what i enter.

And i would like it to print the WHOLE line of what i search for. 
the information is split using "::" in a single line. so
ID::Name::BooksBorrowed::PhoneNumber
ID...
ID...
so every line has different user.
so when i search for a user's "name" it should print out that whole line which the user's "name" was found on.

so im wondering does anyone know where my mistake is and how can i fix it? i searched many times online, but just none worked. i tried with bufferedReaders, still nothing.

how would i make it recognise the user input and search for it.

Comment: Don't you suppose to use `UserSearchLine` here `if(UserLine.equals(SearchUser.usersearch));` instead of `SearchUser.usersearch`?

Comment: yeah i think that was a mistake, i changed it, however the error still persists.
i removed the "final String"